# Django ManyToManyField Unique item

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am writing a model which is below:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        related_name='group_admins'
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        blank=True,
        related_name='group_members'
    )
```

I want a Person Can't join another group if he belongs to a Group.

I mean, group members or a Group admin can't join a new group if he/she belongs to in a group.

Can anyone help me to make it happen?

Comment: Why do you wanna build this yourself? You should look into [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#using-the-django-authentication-system) or at least make use of the Django models.

Comment: I am developing a hostel management system, I have seen the documentation but i couldnt solve myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a person can only be in one group, then you aren't looking at a many-to-many relationship, but a many-to-one relationship, which in Django is represented by `models.ForeignKey` [0]

In your case it may look something like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    member_of = models.ForeignKey('Group', related_name='group_members')
    admin_of = models.ForeignKey('Group', related_name='group_admins', null=True, blank=True)

class Group(models.Model):
    # name = models.CharField() etc
```

Note the use of `related_name`, it will allow you, from a `Group` instance, to query all the members and admins

[0] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/